# Python Asterisk AGI imported script won't run?

Tags: python-2.7, asterisk, raspberry-pi3, agi

I recently started a project where I've ro use asterisk and AGI. So I started to learn how AGI works in python by using an example found on the internet. But when I paste the example and try to run the module in Python, shell gives me in red font "ARGS: ['usr/bla bla]" ( You can see the clear output in attached image). I don't know why this happens and program won't stop running (When I try to close the shell, it says program still runs).

Note: I'm using Python in my Raspberry Pi.  Pyst package has been installed there.

[image: screenshot of the script and shell]

In above image, left side is the script that I tried to run. Or I can say the example I got from the internet. Rightside it shows the shell. You can see the program still runs.

Please help me. How can I run this properly?

Answer (score 0):

Sure it not give any output.

It wait for INPUT.

Please re-read documentation about AGI, give script needed info to STDIN if for some weird reason you run it not from asterisk.

Comment: Thank you. But when I run help(asterisk.agi) , it shows __init__(self) which I believe means it doesn't need a stdin as a parameter? Can you help me sir?

Comment: AGI script waiting for info from asterisk. You should not run it from command line. Read any article about AGI, it descibed EVERYWHERE.

Comment: this is the article i got my example from. http://www.itp-redial.com/class/weekly-notes/week4-notes/agi-scripting-with-python   . In there it says to execute. But when I execute it by double clicking , terminal comes and vanishes. Please help me. I couldn't find anything from the internet so far. At least suggest me a good article. Thank you.

Comment: That one article is good. I am not gooing write better one. From that page "The application should wait indefinitely for input (which it is expecting from Asterisk through STDIN). You can simulate this by hitting return a couple of times. You should see some semblance of the commands that are sent to Asterisk via STDOUT."

Comment: Thank you sir. I found that to execute it we should use exten => 1,2,agi,easy.py where easy.py is the agi python code. But I don't have idea where I should run this statement.

Comment: That is not statement that is asterisk dialplan. Please read general book about asterisk. REALLY no way do agi scripting for asterisk without understanding how asterisk works. Can recommend read ORelly's "Asterisk the future of telephony".

Comment: It is not situation when you read one page and able do it. You need have basic background. Minimum set is : sip trunking, asterisk config files, asterisk dialplan, asterisk applications.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I want. I couldn't find a good reference book about agi. Thank you